# Print values of thread_info for a given process

Tags: linux, gdb, kernel

From the memory dump of a given process, I would like to extract the values of thread_info, e.g. preempt_count.

It is defined on x86 in :

```
struct thread_info {
    struct task_struct  *task;
    struct exec_domain  *exec_domain;
    __u32                flags;
    __u32                status;
    __u32                cpu;
    int                  preempt_count;
    mm_segment_t         addr_limit;
    struct restart_block restart_block;
    void __user         *sysenter_return;
#ifdef CONFIG_X86_32
    unsigned long        previous_esp;
    __u8                 supervisor_stack[0];
#endif
    int                  uaccess_err;
};
```

and resides at the bottom of the stack of the process.

On x86, the address of the thread_info structure can be obtained by masking out the 13 least-significant bits of the stack pointer (assuming a stack size of 8KB). This is done by the current_thread_info() function (cf. Love, "Linux Kernel Development").

I tested for a process with pid 2419 (I started /bin/bash), using gdb to obtain the value of the stackpointer and python to get the memory address:

```
$ gdb --pid 2419
(gdb) print $sp
$1 = (void *) 0xbf870fa8
(gdb) python print "%x" % (0xbf870fa8 & 0xffffe000)
bf870000
```

Hence, thread_info should reside at bf870000:

```
(gdb) x/40xb 0xbf870000
0xbf870000:     0x08    0x66    0x2d    0x0a    0x08    0x66    0x2d    0x0a
0xbf870008:     0x88    0x8f    0x08    0x0a    0xb8    0x18    0x07    0x08
0xbf870010:     0xe8    0xe6    0x60    0x0a    0x08    0x65    0x2d    0x0a
0xbf870018:     0x08    0x60    0x61    0x0a    0x88    0x8f    0x08    0x0a
0xbf870020:     0x08    0x66    0x2d    0x0a    0x88    0x8f    0x08    0x0a
```

The problem is: How can I connect this data to the thread_info struct?

Now I could map structure to memory, however, I think the address 0xbf870000 is wrong...

```
(gdb) symbol-file /usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-3.2.0-52-generic-pae
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-3.2.0-52-generic-pae...done.
(gdb) p (struct thread_info *)0xbf870000
$2 = (struct thread_info *) 0xbf870000
(gdb) p *$2
$4 = {task = 0xa2d6608, exec_domain = 0xa2d6608, flags = 168333192, status = 134682808, cpu = 174122728, preempt_count = 170747144, addr_limit = {seg = 174153736}, restart_block = {
    fn = 0xa088f88, {futex = {uaddr = 0xa2d6608, val = 168333192, flags = 174153736, bitset = 134622139, time = 580707212407115656, uaddr2 = 0x1524}, nanosleep = {clockid = 170747400, 
        rmtp = 0xa088f88, expires = 578197684496719880}, poll = {ufds = 0xa2d6608, nfds = 168333192, has_timeout = 174153736, tv_sec = 134622139, tv_nsec = 168333192}}}, 
  sysenter_return = 0xbf87007c, previous_esp = 4294967264, supervisor_stack = 0xbf870044 "\274F\017\b\002", uaccess_err = 135218876}
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Could map structure to memory, however, I think the address 0xbf870000 is wrong...

(gdb) symbol-file /usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-3.2.0-52-generic-pae

Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-3.2.0-52-generic-pae...done.
(gdb) p (struct thread_info *)0xbf870000
$2 = (struct thread_info *) 0xbf870000
(gdb) p *$2
$4 = {task ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Employed russian is right, the stuff lies in kernel space. You can use stap (apt-get install systemtap on ubuntu) to examine the structures.

Note that you can use that for any process to examine thread_info and task_struct.

This was my workflow:

1. Start shell and type echo $$ to get pid of shell

`$> echo $$
5296`

2. Create stap script thread_info.stp:

```
#cf. /usr/share/doc/systemtap-doc/examples/process/dumpstack.stp

// Add a dummy probe for loading kernel symbols.
probe kernel.function("printk") { next }

probe begin {
        process_pid = target()

        //pid2task(process_pid) defined in /usr/share/systemtap/tapset/task.stp
        //returns task_struct of process_pid
        //pt:long serves as "pointer to task_struct"
        pt = pid2task(process_pid) 

        //task_execname(pt): defined in /usr/share/systemtap/tapset/task.stp
        printf("Execname of process %d: %s\n", process_pid, task_execname(pt) )
        pt_utime = @cast(pt, "task_struct", "kernel<linux/sched.h>")->utime
        printf("Utime of process: %d\n", pt_utime)

        //taken from task_cpu@/usr/share/systemtap/tapset/task.stp
        ti = (@defined(@cast(pt, "task_struct", "kernel<linux/sched.h>")->stack)
          ? @cast(pt, "task_struct", "kernel<linux/sched.h>")->stack
          : @cast(pt, "task_struct", "kernel<linux/sched.h>")->thread_info);
        printf("Cpu: %d\n", @cast(ti, "thread_info", "kernel<linux/sched.h>")->cpu)

        //does the above code make sense?
        printf("%s == %s ???\n", task_execname(pt), task_execname(@cast(ti, "thread_info", "kernel<linux/sched.h>")->task))

        exit()
}
```

3. As root, type

   $> stap -x 5296 thread_info.stp

   Execname of process 5296: bash

   Utime of process: 174

   Cpu: 0

   bash == bash ???

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are very confused:

The `struct thread_info` is a *kernel* structure, residing in the *kernel* 8K thread stack.

Yet you expect to find it in *user space* stack, by masking and casting user-space stack pointer.

The data you seek is *not* in user-space. If it were, the user-space program would be free to overwrite it and cause all manner of mayhem to the kernel.

Answer (score -2):

Basically it sound reasonable to retrieve a thread_info data in this way, however. I am not very familiar with GBD, please correct me if I am wrong. When you attach a thread via gdb and then "print $sp" at the moment, how do you know the register is using as a "stack pointer" rather than "general puspose register"? You should retrieve the right SP where "sp" is really assigned as a stack.

Comment: You are *very* wrong in just about every point of your answer.

Comment: You'd better explain where is misleading part. Please see the following example why I was saying "SP is not always stand for a stack pointer purpose." ( In arm assembly)

    Mov r4, SP  ---> SP saved
    LDR SP, [r5] ---> SP start used as a general purpose register.
    LDMIA sp!, {r0-r3}
    CMP r0, #0
    BEQ bad_value
    MOV r4, sp    ----> SP restored

Comment: BY the way, as far as I can see, 0xbf870000 is the kernel address and typing "info stack" will show the call stack are in kernel space, anyway, I am not expert in GDB and welcome for any explanations.